# JavaScript Class properties inside constructor

Tags: javascript, class, oop, properties

Defined one property outside the constructor like **name**, and one inside like **this.id**, but when i initialized, I got property, which was outside the constructor.

I created one class **person** and defined a property **name** (not in constructor) like this

```
class Person {
  name;
}

let instance_ = new Person()
console.log(instance_)
```

I got output

> Person {name: undefined}

Then, I defined other class **Employee** and defined a property **id** (in constructor)

```
class Employee {
  constructor() {
    this.id
  }
}

let instanceEmp_ = new Employee()
console.log(instanceEmp)
```

The output I got

> Employee {} //Didn't get **id** property

I didn't get **id** property in class **Employee**. Why?

Comment: You didn't assign any value to that `id` so it treated is as a getter not  a setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign something into that property, otherwise js thinks it's a getter

```js
class Employee {
  constructor() {
    this.id = undefined
  }
}

let instanceEmp = new Employee()
console.log(instanceEmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to pass an id variable to the constructor:

```
class Employee {
   constructor(id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
}

let instanceEmp = new Employee()
console.log(instanceEmp) // Employee {id: undefined}
```